# JsonConverter DeserializeObject Single or Multiple to Generic class

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net

I want to deserialize to my json string to my generic class. But i want to do this in one method. When i call this link;

Here is my Code;
Its My class:

```
public class Test
{
    public string userId { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Its My Deserialize class:

```
    private static async Task<IRestResponse<T>> MapResponse<T>(HttpResponseMessage response) where T : class
    {
        var restResponse = new WebApiRestResponse<T>
        {
            Content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(),
            StatusCode = response.StatusCode
        };
        try
        {
            var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "text/plain")
                restResponse.Exception = new RestInteractionException(body);
            else
                restResponse.Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(body); ;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            restResponse.Exception = e;
        }

        return restResponse;
    }


 public interface IRestResponse
    {

        string Content { get; }


        Exception Exception { get; set; }

        HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; }
    }

    public interface IRestResponse<T> : IRestResponse
    {
        List<T> Data { get; }

    }
```

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

Its returned to single object.

when i call this link;

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

MapResponse class make to deserialize to json to generic class. But sometimes i call single object, sometimes i call list object. so how can i do this in this code?

Best regards

Comment: You need to write the code that implements the logic you are describing. Alternatively, you could provide sample code that you have tried and people may give you a hand here.

Comment: It is impossible to understand your problem without posting your code. On SO, people take their free time to help you out of a problem. It's not asking too much that you take the time to adequately describe your problem.

Comment: I share code. i hope you understand

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182)

Comment: I did it. But its return stack overflow error. When you try single object it says to you System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Item]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/SgM0LY

Comment: @user1436795 - you would need to use `SingleOrArrayConverter<Item>` where `Item` is the root object that might or might not be in an array.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/GJMaYi.  Or `SingleOrArrayConverter<Test>` for your `Test` class.

Comment: Thanks Alot of. Its working so good.Have a nice day. You should write answer here and i will check it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can have list as result sometimes, return it as a list always if you want single method. When you have a single object, just create new list and add it.

Comment: I share my code. But i cant understand when its single, when its list. How can i understand it? can you tell me. I can return list in every condition.